# What is the definition of the SCHEMA_HISTORY.execution_time in Flyway?

Tags: flyway

I cant find any documentation of this table on https://flywaydb.org and Google. This doesn't look like seconds.  I was leaning towards Milliseconds but logged *execution time* items in the form of `mm:ss.SSS` are not lining up with the numbers in the `SCHEMA_HISTORY` table although they are close.

Answer (score 10):

The `execution_time` field is measured in milliseconds:

`/**
     * The execution time (in millis) of this migration.
     */
    private final int executionTime;`

Source: flyway [source code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/schemahistory/AppliedMigration.java#L69)